# Unable to create Web Service Client from WSDL URL in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I'm trying to create a Web Service Client using the option `WSDL URL` in NetBeans IDE 7.0.  Unfortunately, it is not able to create one and is failing with the following error:

**Saxon cannot write a DOMResult unless saxon9-dom.jar is on the classpath**

[image]

After seeing this error message, I even confirmed whether `saxon9-dom.jar` is added to the Libraries in NetBeans.  Yes, it is already available. I don't know why still the error is appearing.  Can somebody let me know what is going wrong?

I'm trying to create web service client for [this WSDL](http://schemas.monster.com/Current/WSDL/MonsterBusinessGateway.wsdl).  I'm choosing `JAX-WS Style` in *Client Style* option while creating New Web Service Client in NetBeans.

**UPDATE:**
After googling, I read about some clues from the following 2 places:

1) http://www.mail-archive.com/fop-dev@xmlgraphics.apache.org/msg09659.html

> This is due to the new event-handling framework that has been added
>   after 0.95. The step in the build process that generates the resource
>   files for the various messages, seems to require a writable DOM
>   implementation.
>
> As the message indicates, Saxon offers such an implementation in a
>   separate JAR, which needs to be added to the classpath when building
>   FOP Trunk.

2) http://xmlbeans.apache.org/sourceAndBinaries/index.html

> Using XPath/XQuery requires an additional download of
>   saxonb9-0-0-4j.zip and placing on the classpath of the files
>   saxon9.jar and saxon9-dom.jar that it contains. The zip is available
>   here. We cannot distribute this zip in a binary distribution due to
>   licensing issues.

So, I thought of changing saxon9-dom.jar in the classpath. I was using saxon9-dom.jar from `saxonb9-1-0-8j.zip` before, but when I tried to include saxon9-dom.jar available in `saxonb9-0-0-8j.zip`, now this error has disappeared and am getting a different error now as shown below.  Any ideas/clues?

[image]

Comment: I got the error "Saxon cannot write a DOMResult unless saxon9-dom.jar is on the classpath" once after adding the -httpproxy parameter to wsimport in netbeans. After I removed it, that error dissapeared. maybe that's your case?

Answer (score 0):

Web Services are described using WSDL files, so in order to create a Web Consumer for them you'll have to specify the WSDL url.

You can obtain it by adding ?WSDL ar the and of the url.

For example:

CrudService.asmx becomes

CrudService.asmx?WSDL

(It you have tested your web service and it appears ?Tester at the end, just replace it with ?WSDL).