# How do I escape '+' in pattern matching to highlight keyword?

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I'm implementing a keyword highlighter in Java.  I'm using `java.util.regex.Pattern` to highlight (making bold) keyword within String content.  The following piece of code is working fine for alphanumeric keywords, but it is not working for some special characters.  For example, in String content, I would like to highlight the keyword `c++` which has the special character + (plus), but it's not getting highlighted properly.  How do I escape `+` character so that `c++` is highlighted?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String content = "java,c++,ejb,struts,j2ee,hibernate";
    System.out.println("CONTENT: " + content);
    String highlight = "C++";

    System.out.println("HIGHLIGHT KEYWORD: " + highlight);

    //highlight = highlight.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("+"), "\\\\+");
    java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\b" + highlight + "\\b", java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    System.out.println("PATTERN: " + pattern.pattern());
    java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Match found!!!");
        for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        content = matcher.replaceAll("<B>" + matcher.group(i) + "</B>");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("RESULT: " + content);
}
```

**Output:**
CONTENT: java,c++,ejb,struts,j2ee,hibernate
HIGHLIGHT KEYWORD: C++
PATTERN: \bC++\b
Match found!!!
c
RESULT: java,**c**++,ejb,struts,j2ee,hibernate

---

I even tried to escape '+' before calling *Pattern.compile* like this,

```
highlight = highlight.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("+"), "\\\\+");
```

but still I'm not able to get the syntax right.  Can somebody help me solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "\\b" 
    + Pattern.quote(highlight)
    + "\\b",
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Update: you are right, the above doesn't work for C++ (`\b` matches word boundaries and doesn't recognize ++ as a word). We need a more complicated solution:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "\\b" 
    + Pattern.quote(highlight)
    + "(?![^\\p{Punct}\\s])", // matches if the match is not followed by
                              // anything other than whitespace or punctuation
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Update in response to comments: it seems that you need more logic in your pattern creation. Here's a helper method to create the pattern for you:

```
private static final String WORD_BOUNDARY = "\\b";
// edit this to suit your neds:
private static final String ALLOWED = "[^,.!\\-\\s]";
private static final String LOOKAHEAD = "(?!" + ALLOWED + ")";
private static final String LOOKBEHIND = "(?<!" + ALLOWED + ")";

public static Pattern createHighlightPattern(final String highlight) {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
            (Character.isLetterOrDigit(highlight.charAt(0)) 
             ? WORD_BOUNDARY : LOOKBEHIND)
            + Pattern.quote(highlight)
            + (Character.isLetterOrDigit(highlight.charAt(highlight.length() - 1))
             ? WORD_BOUNDARY : LOOKAHEAD),
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    return pattern;
}
```

And here is some test code to check that it works:

```
private static void testMatch(final String haystack, final String needle) {
    final Matcher matcher = createHighlightPattern(needle).matcher(haystack);
    if (!matcher.find())
        System.out.println("Failed to find pattern " + needle);
    while (matcher.find())
        System.out.println("Found additional match: " + matcher.group() +
                           " for pattern " + needle);
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String testString = "java,c++,hibernate,.net,asp.net,c#,spring";
    testMatch(testString, "java");
    testMatch(testString, "c++");
    testMatch(testString, ".net");
    testMatch(testString, "c#");
}
```

When I run this method, I don't see any output (which is good :-))

Comment: +1 Docs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Tomalak actually, more like http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Hm, the link itself is correct but obviously it breaks at the unencoded closing paren — or did you mean that linking to Java 1.6 is better?

Comment: @Tomalak yes, that's what I meant (didn't add direct link to Pattern.quote(), lazy me)

Comment: @Sean I don't see where the Java 1.6 `Pattern.quote()` method would be any better than the one from 1.5. Even their respective documentations are absolutely the same. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak in this particular case: true. Generally: it's about time that JDK 5 was abandoned. JDK 7 is around the corner, after all.

Comment: @Sean: I concur. It was the first hit on Google for some reason, and I was too lazy to explicitly look for the 1.6 documentation for this particular case. I was not trying to endorse the use of an old version of Java. - Following this logic, in half a year's time your comment would need a correction, too. ;-)

Comment: @Sean: Great!! This is working absolutely as I expected. BTW, though you explained that `matches if the match is not followed by anything other than whitespace or punctuation`, I couldn't able to get/understand this completely.  Can you help/educate me to understand this expression?

Comment: won't work if `highlight = "c"`. it will result in something like this `<b>c</b>++ , <b>c</b>#` as well.

Comment: @Gnanam see [Special Constructs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special)

Comment: @RubyDubee true but that could be solved by replacing the punct thingy with something more specific, e.g. `.,!`. But there will always be corner cases.

Comment: Yes! but, I think, splitting and checking for individual strings will be more correct and readable in this case! What do you think?

Comment: @RubyDubee True, but it will make things like case-insensitivity almost impossible

Comment: @Sean: Thanks, I'll read about that. Do you've answer/comment for my another question http://stackoverflow.com/q/6674336/181870?

Comment: @Sean: Just one more clarification here.  If my *content* contains  `java,c#,asp.net,.net,c++` and if I want to highlight `.net`, then this pattern is highlighting like this: `java,c#,asp<B>.net</B>,.net,c++`.  As you can see, `.net` as a separate keyword is not highlighted. Any idea/approach on how to make this keyword highlighted, without affecting any other scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `\b` word boundary anchor is not matching, because `+` is a non word character and I assume there is a whitespace following that is also a non word character.

A word boundary `\b` is matching a change from a word character (Member in `\w`) to a non word character (no member of `\w`).

Also if you want to match a `+` literally you have to escape it. Here you are searching for `C++` that means match at least one `C` and the `++` is a possessive quantifier matching at least 1 `C` and does not backtrack.

Try changing your pattern to something like this

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\b" + highlight + "(?=\s)", java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

`(?=\s)` is a positive lookahead that will check if there is a whitespace following your `highlight`

Additionally you will need to esacape the + your are searching for.

Comment: @Gnanam, I am not sure in Java, `\+` or `\\+`

Comment: @Gnanam, combine my answer and @Sean answer. His `Pattern.quote(highlight)` should escape the `+` in your search string.

Comment: @Gnanam, What is not working? How does the code looks now and what is it doing wrong?

Comment: In fact, this is totally failing and is not highlighting even simple keywords like "java", "ejb", etc.  It is not highlighting for the keyword "c++" as well.  Code looks like this: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(highlight) + "(?=\\s)", java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Comment: @stema +1 for your approach, but I think the OP has no spaces in his String, so you'll have to replace the positive lookahead with a negative one (as in my answer)

Comment: @Sean I think his string is only an example, but you are right I forgot about punctuation. (+1 for a better answer)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is here :

```
Pattern.compile("\\Q"+highlight+"\\E", java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Keyword which I want to highlight should be a "standalone" word and **not** part of a larger word.  For example, if there is a String content containing "java,javascript" and my keyword is "java", then your pattern will highlight both *java* and *javascript* here.  Output is: `<B>java</B>,<B>java</B>script`

Comment: Then surround it with \\b ... like this : 

`java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\b\\Q"+highlight+"\\E\\b", java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`

Comment: Even tried surrounding with `\\b`, it is not highlighting the keyword `c++`.

Comment: Yeah! Sean's answer seems to do well here! but its also not perfect. I think you will have to go with the traditional way of splitting and checking individual strings! but still let's think!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keyword does not begin or end with punctuation, here is a commented regex which uses lookahead and lookbehind to achieve your desired matching behavior:

```java
// Compile regex to match a keyword or keyphrase.
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(
    "(?<=[\\s'\".?!,;:]|^)  # Word preceded by ws, quote, punct or BOS.\n" +

    // Escape any regex metacharacters in the keyword phrase.
    java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(highlight) + " # Keyword to be matched.\n" +

    "(?=[\\s'\".?!,;:]|$)   # Word followed by ws, quote, punct or EOS.", 
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
```

Note that this solution works even if your keyword is a phrase containing spaces.